# How I can make live stream URL on swift?

Tags: ios, swift, streaming

I have a list of URLs like this one: http://198.100.125.242:80. But I don't understand how to make them stream on swift

Comment: Do you want to play streams via url or record live streams ?

Comment: @FaresBenHamouda I want to play streams

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a good library for playing streams in Swift: https://github.com/piemonte/Player

Compatible with cocoapods and carthage :

```
# CocoaPods
swift_version = "3.0"
pod "Player", "~> 0.5.0"

# Carthage
github "piemonte/Player" ~> 0.5.0
```

Comment: Actually I don't know what kind of mediadata will come. It may be audio or video. But thank you for your help! I'll try it

Comment: Normally, it should work also with audio, with a little hack with the the player instance.

Comment: I'll try some other solution, thank you for you help!

Comment: I'm so sorry! They gave me bad links. I've try with other link and everything work good.